# OSX - How to implement the export window like Preview.app?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I'm building a small non-document-based app for OSX. And I want to implement the export sheet just like Preview.app does:

[image: Preview Export Sheet]

Note the export sheet gives the user a chance to choose the file type and related stuff.

My guess is that the sheet is a system-level out-of-box feature, but I failed to find it, so how can I implement something like this one? Big thanks!

PS: I'm deploying the app to 10.7 or later.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's an [`NSSavePanel`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/applicationkit/classes/NSSavePanel_Class/Reference/Reference.html) with a custom [accessory view](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/applicationkit/classes/NSSavePanel_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSSavePanel/setAccessoryView%3a).

Comment: Thanks omz, shall I implement mine view as well, or is there any already-made view for developers?

Answer (score 0):

IKImageKit has an Accessoire view exactly for that.